# Best practice to store App Key in Laravel

Tags: laravel, security, encryption, cpanel

I have been doing a lot of research on this and I can't seem to find a definitive answer. Obviously these days security is a big issue, hacks are going on all over the place of major companies that invest millions into security and they're still getting hacked.

I work on Laravel a lot and use shared hosting with Hostgator or some similar company of high report. Laravel comes with a built in function for encrypting database info and decrypting to the user when requested.

However, I have a question on how secure this ACTUALLY is. If someone gets into my cPanel, my app key which is used for encryption is right there in front of them. Granted, my cPanel password is the one that's auto-generated by Hostgator and it's complete jibberish with semicolons and alphanumeric strings all over, so it's not easy to guess.

But I'm trying to learn a little bit more about security. If my app key in my `env` file is locked securely behind my cPanel login, is Laravels built in "`encrypt()`" method "enough" to call an app "secure"? Is there other measures within Laravel or my host provider that could make it more secure than just tight passwords? Is there some sort of practice of referencing the app key through an external source that's not located in the cPanel area? So even if my cPanel got hacked, my app key wouldn't be in those files and get exposed?

Comment: The question I would have in response to this is when and where are you using `encrypt()`? Sensitive information, like passwords in a `users` table should be hashed, and not encrypted. `hash()` is a one-way method that works by comparison (so you need to know the unhashed value before comparing, and there's no way to get the unhashed value from the hashed value). `encrypt()` can be reversed using `decrypt()`, and is used for obfuscation (making information not appear as something else until a process un-obfuscates it)

Comment: Hi @TimLewis, thanks for responding. I have a feature that allows a user to store banking information as part of their profile. I encrypt it in the controller on the way to the database ```$user->bank_number = encrypt($request->bank_number)``` . Then I decrypt it in the view when the user wants to view it in their profile. This isn't live yet because i'm paranoid about it.

Comment: Hmm, fair point. That would be a question for the bank though, specifically "what can someone do with a user's bank number?" If the response is "not much", then this likely isn't a concern. If the response is "withdraw or transfer everything", then it's a major concern, and you'll have to rethink your approach. Maybe rely on external payment options, like Stripe, PayPal, etc. and don't store banking information. All that being said, external hosting should have security practices in place that prevent anyone from accessing sensitive information, and a strong password should stop it early too.

Comment: The answer is "withdraw or transfer everything". I have a buddy that asked me to build an investor portal for him. So I can't use stripe or paypal since the transfers need to be initiated straight from bank account to bank account (investment restrictions in my state). The transfer would not happen within the app itself, but after the client contacts the admin team, the admins can use the info on file to process their investment request through the company. So it's strictly storage, but still, i don't want ignorance to make me guilty of a persons theft of funds

Comment: Yeah, that's totally understandable. I've done something similar with a method known as EFT, or Electronic Funds Transfer. Basically, on the bottom of a cheque in my country, there's an institution, transit and account number listed, and using those, funds can be transferred between accounts. On their own, those numbers can't do much, as they need to be sent to a bank on a periodic basis to be processed, so I'd look into that approach and see if its an option for you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Tim. As always, it's been a pleasure. If you think of anything afterwards, please stop by again

Comment: No problem! Always happy to help :) Best of luck in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm  not a security expert, but there are a few points I can share from my experience in working at highly-secured companies.

First, Laravel itself is fine. You can generally trust open source software since it's transparent and security bugs get discovered and addressed early. So you don't need to *improve* Laravel, just use it as is, preferably an LTS version.

Then, CPanel is a liability. You should minimize weak points on your system, i.e. those that are externally accessible. Get a VPS or a private server and access it via an SSH, don't use tools like CPanel and PhpMyAdmin on it. The less software you have that talks to the outer world, the less vulnerable you are to bugs in that software.

In my current company the production server can only be accessed via SSH from a *single* IP address, the address of the dev server. So I log in to dev server first, and then log in from there to the prod. It denies all connections from all other IPs.

If you are limited to using CPanel or something similar, consider protecting the login page with HTTP Basic Auth, some hosting providers allow that.

You also want to keep your system and software up to date. Not too new either as that may have bugs that haven't been caught yet. Our devops prefer to have it a couple of minor versions behind, so that the community has time to test it out and get hacked for you.

That's all I know as a web-dev, sure enough there are special tools and ddos protection services but that's beyond a dev's concern imo. If you just follow these steps, you should be safe. Hope that helped a bit, cheers :)

Comment: Couldnt agree more about CPanel. Shared hosting in general is a liability. Although hosting companies do a pretty good job at keeping the servers secure, I would say that the entire server is as secure as the least secure website running on one of the shared accounts on that server.

Comment: Let me clarify your comment....my website is vulnerable if it's on a server being shared by a less secure website?

Comment: @maximus1127 I would say so, yes. If security of utmost importance, as it is in your case, it is always a good idea to go for private hosting. You get to implement all the security it needs.